# How come a printf is performed after a true condition was tested?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C ,so please forgive me if this question is stupid or was asking weirdly.

I'm reading *C primer plus* and one of the examples in *Chapter-8* is some loop that testing whether the user entered - *`a newline character or not`* ,which I couldn't understand.

The code is short so I will show it to you:

```
int main(void)
{
    int ch; /* character to be printed */
    int rows, cols; /* number of rows and columns */
    printf("Enter a character and two integers:\n");
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if (scanf("%d %d",&rows, &cols) != 2)
            break;
        display(ch, rows, cols);
        while (getchar() != '\n')
            continue;
        printf("Enter another character and two integers;\n");
        printf("Enter a newline to quit.\n");
    }
    printf("Bye.\n");
    return 0;
}
void display(char cr, int lines, int width) // the function to preform the printing of the arguments being passed
```

What i dont understand is right here:

```
while (getchar() != '\n')
                continue;
            printf("Enter another character and two integers;\n");
            printf("Enter a newline to quit.\n");
```

First of all, the `while (getchar() != '\n')` is testing the first ch was entered right?
Second, if that is true, how come the continue is not skiping the printf statements and going to the first while? isn't it what it should do?

Tnx

Comment: "I'm reading C primer plus" <--- That is your biggest problem!! Kill that book with fire!!! RTFN

Comment: The `continue` is just smoke. It'd better be `while (getchar() != '\n');`.

Comment: Thanks allot :) @Daniel Fischer

Comment: The `getchar() != '\n'` reads a character, compares it with `'\n'`, and if it isn't, it is **utterly gone**. Do as @TonyTheLion says. Better check http://lysator.liu.se/c for decent C texts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there are no braces after the `while` statement, only the very next line is included in the loop. So, `continue` continues the while loop until a new line character is found and then the execution continues to the `printf` statements.

It is equivalent to this:

```
 while (getchar() != '\n')
 {
    continue;
 }
```

Comment: +1 for getting to the real problem of the asking person here.

Comment: thanks so much for the reply! but i though if the compiler see the getchar() function, it will stop and ask for the user to enter a character, then test it, and then continue...so this getchar() in the while is testing the previous input? @SShaheen

Comment: @Nir While there is still unconsumed input in the input buffer, `getchar()` just reads a character from the buffer. Usually, input from `stdin` is only sent to the programme after the user pressed Return/Enter, and thus there's always a newline in the buffer for `getchar()` to eventually find. If there is no unconsumed input in the buffer, and the stream isn't closed or corrupt, `getchar()` blocks until there has been input delivered to the buffer.

Comment: @DanielFischer exactly what i needed to understand. you rock.

Comment: what do you mean by that? @HWende

Comment: @Nir Also note that [`continue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ceyyskb(v=vs.80).aspx) goes to the next iteration of a `do`, `for`, or `while` loop. So if the `while` would have been an `if` instead, the program would have behaved as you had thought.

Comment: Right! just tested it :) tnx @SShaheen

Comment: @Nir Since my answer appears to have helped you a lot, please do me the favor of accepting my answer by clicking the checkmark under the voting arrows. Thanks!

Comment: @SShaheen sure! been meaning to do that anyway ;)

Comment: @Nir I was pointing out that the curly braces probably were what you did get wrong. I wanted to emphasize that this answer therefore was the most helpful one for you.

Answer (score 1):

The continue is applied to the `while` just before the two `printf`-s so when you enter `\n` you will get out of the innermost while back to the line

```
printf("Enter another character and two integers;\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `continue`applies to the closest `while`loop.

```
while (stuff)
  continue;
```

is the same as

```
while (stuf);
```

(note the semicolon).

You just say "keep looping until the condition becomes false".

Answer (score 0):

Here the while() loop is associated with only continue statement.
So it dont have relation with printf statements..........